# azure ad b2c mfa passwordless authentication technical profile merge screens

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am writing custom profile for azure AD b2c and using [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/scenarios/phone-number-passwordless) starter kit.

I need to make some changes as when I run `SignUpOrSignInWithPhone` user journey it opens first input screen.

[image]

Here you can see we can provide valid number and click continue.

Then, it shows second screen like this:

[image]

Here it asking me to select different country or default and provide valid phone number:

I just want skip the first screen or replace the first screen and it should render screen first time with country dropdown and on validation I receive OTP.

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInWithPhone">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="signuporsignin-phone">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithPhone" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ChangePhoneNumber" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninPhoneExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <!-- <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninPhoneExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneInputPage-ChangePhoneNumberPolicy" /> -->
        <!-- <ClaimsExchange Id="ChangePhoneNumber" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneInputPage-ChangePhoneNumberClaimsProviderSelection" /> -->
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninPhoneExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Phone-Only" />
        <!-- <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninPhoneExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserDiscoveryUsingLogonPhoneNumber-Common" /> -->
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithPhone" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhoneNumber" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ChangePhoneNumber" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneInputPage-ChangePhoneNumberClaimsProviderSelection" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

I commented the code which I tried to replace first screen with second one, but none is working as I need.
Thanks in advance please do not make my question rejected. I am struggling for last 2 days.

Comment: What you want to do is actually skip all of Step 1+2 and go directly to Step 3 "SignInWithPhone". That subjourney is what causes you to see the second screenshot. Doing so will remove the ability to sign up and recover your account.

Answer (score 0):

You user journey should look like this

```xml
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInWithPhone">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="SignInWithPhone" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isChangePhoneNumber</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="ChangePhoneNumber" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>hasFullProfile</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

Comment-out/Remove this section in `PhoneVerificationPage1` technical profile.

```xml
         <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetNationalNumberAndCountryCodeIfInternationalFormat" />
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="PhoneNumberToNationalNumber" />
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
```

Comment: thanks @Jas Suri - MSFT , but I am unable to see Sign up now and change phone numbers links.